# Comma before 'as'

Tags: commas

I would like to know whether a comma is needed after 'as'. Here I have some illustrative sentences:

1. "The heat pumps operate during periods with high outside
   temperatures(,) as this increases their efficiencies"
2. "The study analyses heat pumps(,) as it is assumed that they will have
   high market share in the future"

Are these commas correct? Grammarly tells me to use these commas (I know that Grammarly is not always right). I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Didn't I see this same question yesterday?

Comment: Thaks Hot Licks for your comment. Where did you see it?

Comment: I tried to find it but apparently it had been deleted.  I remember it because it similarly asked about a comma "after as" in the title.

Comment: OK, I guess it was your question about a comma "after like".  Pretty much the same answer.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for your answer. So this means I should use the commas

Comment: Use a comma if what follows is optional; leave the comma out if what follows is necessary. Whether it is or not, is up to you as the author. In theory, you determine the meaning. (And, theoretically, the meaning is different depending on the presence or absence of the comma.) Otherwise. look in a style guide. You can normally tell if it's essential or not if you replace the comma with an opening parenthesis, and put a closing parenthesis at the end of the sentence. Is everything in parentheses an afterthought? If you remove everything after the comma, does it harm the basic meaning?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. To be tottaly honest, for me it is extremely difficult to estimate whether the sentence following the comma is necessary or not. How do you define necessary? In my two examples, both comma-sentences could be removed and the sentences would be grammaticarly correct. However, content-wise the comma-sentences are definetly essential as they explain the main-clause

Comment: Does anybody have a comment regarding my last comment? For me it is difficult to estimate if a sentece is necessary or not. Shall I focus more on the gramatical correctness or on the meaning. Would you use a comma in the two sentences from my original quesiton.